# npm i gives code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect', type: 'system' error

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, package.json

I was trying to install the packages for my angular project using npm i. It is giving the below message for each of the package,
[image]

Is it related to network or proxy settings?

Comment: Yes, most probably the proxy does not let the request trough.

Comment: This issue may be because of your proxy settings, also try increasing timeout duration in .npmrc file